# How can I add a title to this 'maintenance mode' function?

Tags: title, maintenance

I use the function below to manually trigger temporary 'maintenance mode'.

```
function maintenance_mode(){
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_themes' ) || !is_user_logged_in() ){
wp_die('<img src="/graphics/header/logo/1.png" />
<p><strong>Site temporarily offline for maintenance.</strong> </p>' );
}}
add_action( 'get_header', 'maintenance_mode' );
```

The page title displays as 'WordPress > error' - which I want to replace with a more appropriate alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a title to the `wp_die()` function or even any other HTML content like heading tags:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_die

But if you are trying to have more control over what's being outputted, you should use the `template_include` filter and use your custom template:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include

EXAMPLE:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'show_maintenance_page', 99 );

function show_maintenance_page( $template ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_themes' ) || !is_user_logged_in() ){
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'maintenance-template.php' ) );
        if ( !empty( $new_template ) ) {
            return $new_template;
        }
    }
    return $template;
```

}

Create a file called `maintenance-template.php` on the root theme folder for this example:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Maintenance mode
*/ 
?>
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/graphics/header/logo/1.png" />
<p>
    <strong>Site temporarily offline for maintenance.</strong> 
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. Passing a title sorts the immediate issue - though I'm interested in your 'template_include' suggestion but having read the linked article still can't understand how to use it in this instance.

Comment: Hi @glvr I've updated my answer with an example, please take a look now

Comment: Ah, thanks... I see. (And I'm sorry for my slow reply.)